# Remove shortcuts from "This PC"

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have added 3 links *(as shown in image)* to `Quick Access`, now I want to delete them from `This PC`.

How can I do this?

[image]

**Options on This PC icons:**

[image]

Comment: right click on each one of them and select delete or remove

Comment: There is no option like that, only option is **Pin to Quick Access**. But no option to remove from `This PC` after that

Comment: can you unpin them?

Comment: I can't do anything with the icons under `This PC`, as you can see the options don't allow me to do

Comment: Check this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/222057/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-%E2%80%9Cthis-pc%E2%80%9D-on-windows-10/  Collapse and remember, or the registry method.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 stores the list of folders under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\` in the registry. On 64-bit versions of Windows 10, the list of folders is also stored under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\` , where it’s used by 32-bit programs in their file save and open windows.

You can use [these](http://cdn3.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Remove-Folders-From-This-PC-on-Windows-10.zip) Registry edits to remove all folders or individual ones depending on your preference.

These have been tested and they work absolutley fine after restarting Explorer.

Source: [How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/222057/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-%E2%80%9Cthis-pc%E2%80%9D-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 3):

Minor update to [@jawad's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1189339/672142). If you would like to remove the `3D Objects` folder from Windows 10 Explorer list use the script below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Remove 3D Objects From This PC

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]
```

Make sure to save as a `.reg` file with ANSI encoding.